# Make tkinter text widget fit to window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, window

I'm making a text editor whose main widget is a Text widget for the user to actually enter text. I need to make the text widget fit to the window when the user resizes the pane. I kind of cheated by making the widget huge, but that's just a makeshift solution to let me work on other parts while I look for a solution. How can I make the Text widget automatically resize to fit the window?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use pack to place the widget, with expand set to `True` and fill set to `BOTH`. Ex:

```python3
    from tkinter import *
    root=Tk()

    text=Text(root)
    text.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    root.mainloop
```