# How to remove the grey line in tkinter under the titlebar in windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, windows-10, tkinter-canvas

I have some code that makes a window with a canvas inside it and can resize. Vertically  works fine, but when I try to resize the window horizontally a grey line appears between the title bar and the rest of the screen that wasn't there before. The line only appears where the window was resized. This isn't a problem on all computers though, it does not appear on windows 7. It does on windows 10.
Is there a way to fix it?
This is my code (Please ignore all the zelf, this is done because the original code is in another language (not programming)):

```
import tkinter
# Custom canvas class    
class Doek(tkinter.Canvas):
    def __init__(zelf, master, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Canvas.__init__(zelf, master, **kwargs)
        zelf.bind("<Configure>", zelf.on_resize)
        zelf.height = zelf.winfo_reqheight()
        zelf.width = zelf.winfo_reqwidth()
    # Method to resize the screen
    def on_resize(zelf,event):
        zelf.width = event.width
        zelf.height = event.height
        zelf.config(width=zelf.width, height=zelf.height) 
# Class that contains all the tkinter related things 
class Window:
    def __init__(zelf):
        zelf.screen = tkinter.Tk()
        zelf.canvas = Doek(zelf.screen, width=800, height=800, bg="white", highlightthickness=0)
        zelf.canvas.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=tkinter.YES)
        zelf.screen.mainloop()

def main():
    my_window = Window()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening, but I can say that you're taking a really roundabout way to do this. I did basically the same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777630/make-tkinter-text-widget-fit-to-window/29777631#29777631) only with a `Text` widget.

Comment: I can't duplicate it on osx. Why do you have the binding? You can remove it and the canvas will still shrink/grow to fit the window.